# can I set val with float value?

Tags: jquery, assign

I want to set the value of a field in my jquery function with a float value, but it doesn't seem to work.Should i convert the float to string before assigning the value to my field ?

```
    var p = ((qI/qO) * 100).toFixed(2);                 
//set the percentage
$j("#jqP100i").val(p);
```

Note : the field has id jqP100i and p is 66.67

Comment: any error in the console and what is the value in `p`

Comment: what is the typeof qI and q0?

Comment: Works fine in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/gMPhf/

Comment: in fact yes it is working in your case, i think the error is elsewhere then, thanks